# Looking for Accurate Ruby, Javascript, or R Excel RATE() or IRR() Function Implementation

Tags: javascript, ruby, r, excel, irr

I'm currently looking for working and accurate implementations of Excel's `RATE()` and `IRR()`. I am coding in Javascript targeting modern browsers and Ruby 2.0.0 within Rails 4. My goal is to be able to calculate APR within a responsive Javascript application with a Rails back-end.

I've looked at and rejected the following options:

[Finance Gem](https://github.com/wkranec/finance): No `RATE()` function. `IRR()` appears to hang for many test vectors.

[Formula.js](http://stoic.com/formula/): No working `RATE()` function. `IRR()` does not work for many test vectors.

[PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel): Has a working `RATE()` function that I converted to [Ruby](https://gist.github.com/jkndrkn/965ae526f2eeb491826d). This failed to work exactly like the PHP version and failed for important test vectors. This likely does have an `IRR()` function but I have not yet tested it. I am not hopeful that I will find one that works but I will test it regardless.

I'm not interested in writing my own implementation from mathematical formulas. I prefer code that appears to have been soundly tested.

**Update:**

I have found a procedure for performing `IRR()` using R that may be accurate enough for our purposes: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/169619.html I will evaluate this solution over the next day or so and update my question if I feel satisfied by it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some testing, I am comfortable with this implementation of `IRR()` in R:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/169619.html

Here it is in the form of a script runnable via the Rscript command:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

periods = as.numeric(args[1])
payment = as.numeric(args[2])
value = as.numeric(args[3])
monthsInYear = 12

timeline <- (0:periods)
payments <- payment + (0 * timeline)
payments[1] <- value

f <- function(r) sum(payments * exp(-r * timeline))
irr <- function(f) uniroot(f, c(0, 1))$root

irr(f) * monthsInYear
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a gem called Exonio:

[github.com/Noverde/exonio](http://github.com/Noverde/exonio)

This gem implements some Excel formulas in Ruby, maybe it could helps you.
To implement the `IRR` method, I use the `Newton` ruby module, which is a root finding algorithm.

Would love to know any improvements to that.